# Summing a stream of integers into a long variable in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Java `Set`, which contains some `Integer` elements. I want to sum its elements using Java 8 streams.

```
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
// Some code that will populate numbers
int sum = numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() //Can overflow!
```

I could use the above code to get the sum but contents of `numbers` are `Integer` elements well below `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and there are a large number of them such that their sum could overflow. How do I convert the stream of `Integer` elements a stream of `Long` elements and sum it safely?

Comment: You do know that a `long` can overflow as well, right? If you are sure that a `long` is sufficient, why not use `long`s from the beginning?

Comment: @Turing85 well, if you have a million entries, but each easily stays below `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it's sum may easily overlow

Comment: @LonelyNeuron That's exactly the case!

Comment: @LonelyNeuron yeah I know. How is that related to my comment?

Comment: @Turing85 if the input values never overflow `int`, it isn't useful to change them to `long`.

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Well, actually it still fits, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E31+*+10%5E6+%3C+2%5E63). Just thinking of it, it's obviously `2 ^ 31 * 2 ^ 32 = 2 ^ (31 + 32) = 2 ^ 63`, so you can fill the `HashSet` to its peak.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `mapToLong(Integer::longValue)` instead of `mapToInt(...)`:

```
long sum = numbers.stream().mapToLong(Integer::longValue).sum();
```

Comment: Great solution. Doesn't introduce new methods without explaining them!

Comment: Note: The nice thing about this solution is that it will create a [LongStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html) which consists of `long`s (opposed to `Long`s) eliminating unnecessary boxing/unboxing!

Answer (score 0):

mapToLong method would be the right one to use. It should avoid the overflow problem since computation is done as long.

`long sum=numbers.stream().mapToLong(Number::longValue).sum();`

Comment: a _slightly_ different variant would be `numbers.stream().mapToLong(Integer::intValue).sum();` the only difference being the function passed to `mapToLong`.

Comment: Please stop upvoting this answer, it is a mere copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49948236/4298200) answer posted earlier